# Exclude property from being indexed

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have created below object which will be mapped to ElasticSearch type. I would like to exclude the `UnivId` property from being indexed:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "Type1")]
public class Type1
{
    // To be ignored
    public string UnivId { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name="Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "descSearch")]
    public string descSearch { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to set the `OptOut` value of the `ElasticProperty` attribute, like the following:

```cs
 [ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
 public string UnivId { get; set; }
```

Comment: OMG, what a poor property name, took me a while to figure it out too.. Thanks

Comment: what is the difference between oput and  [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]? do they do the same job?

Comment: just for the people ever end up here. The difference between these 2 explained on this url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748258/index-fieldindexoption-no-vs-optout-true

Comment: Anyone who knows how to do this in Nest 2?

Comment: @beruic, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35992605/443310 Alexandre B just gave some light on it

Answer (score 17):

In NEST 2.0 ElasticPropertyAttribute is replaced by per type attributes (StringAttribute, DateAttribute...). I used Ignore parameter to exclude property.

Exemple for string :

```
[String(Ignore = true)]
public string Id {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Btw, do you know how to ignore nested properties in code base mapping (in NEST 2.0)?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual take a look at the automap docs for ways to ignore properties - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html#ignoring-properties

Comment: @RussCam when did they just update those docs?? That-is-AWESOME!

Answer (score 3):

If using Nest 5.0+, [per the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ignoring-properties.html#ignoring-properties) several ways to ignore a field:

---

`Ignore` attribute should work:

```
using Nest;

[Ignore]
public string UnivId { get; set; }
```

`JsonIgnore` can also be used since `Newtonsoft.Json` is the default serializer used by Nest.

---

Another way is to use type specific [attribute mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/attribute-mapping.html#attribute-mapping) associated with the property. For example, since it's a `string` then use `Text` attribute:

```
[Text(Ignore = true)]
public string UnivId { get; set; }
```

or if an `int` use `Number`:

```
[Number(Ignore = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

---

In addition, instead of using an explicit attribute on the property, the mapping can be ignored using `.DefaultMappingFor<...` on `ConnectionSettings` (see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ignoring-properties.html#ignoring-properties) for more detail)

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings()
    .DefaultMappingFor<Type1>(m => m.Ignore(p => p.UnivId);
```

---

However, if want to *conditionally* ignore an attribute if the value is null then use the following [`Newtonsoft.Json` attribute with null handling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyPropertyLevelSetting.htm):

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string UnivId { get; set; }
```

I found the above useful when doing [partial updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) on a doc but wanted to re-use the same C# class for indexing and avoid overwriting existing values in the index.