# Index = FieldIndexOption.No vs OptOut =true?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

what is the difference between

```
[ElasticProperty(OptOut =true)]
```

and

```
[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
```

according to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063839/c-sharp-nest-elasticsearch-exclude-object-property-from-being-indexed), it is said that `optout = true` doesnt index the property. I thought `Index = FieldIndexOption.No` is doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ease of explanation, lets consider the class below:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "blog")]
public class Blog
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "title", Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

When you index an object of class `Blog`, value of field `Comments` is completely ignored. Simply put, Elasticsearch has no knowledge of the field `Comments`. It is simply to be used by your client application maybe for some book-keeping purposes. The mapping definition of type `blog` will be as under:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "blog": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `title` field is present. If marked as `Index = FieldIndexOption.No`, you cannot search for values in the `title` field but you can certainly retrieve its value in the matching documents of a search request. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is this attribute removed in Nest 2.0.2? I cant anymore find it. Do you know about it?

Comment: @batmaci - I think this wa renamed to `[Object(Ignore = true)]` (or `[String(Ignore = true)]`)